# Ошибка конфигурации nginx

Tags: django, nginx, config, vds

Есть конфиг

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.ru;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
root /root/project;
}

location / {
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/root/project/project.sock;
}
}
```

При sudo nginx -t он выдаёт ошибку

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/n                                                    ginx.conf:62
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит, что nginx не может найти папку /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project.

- Если папка /etc/nginx/sites-available/project существует, то создайте symlink на нее в /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, тем самым активируя сайт.
- Если нет, вам решать, что делать. Либо создайте сам сайт и перезапустите nginx. Либо если project как таковой вам не нужен, сотрите соответствующую конфигурацию nginx.

Comment: Спасибо, удалил битую symlink и создал новую, ошибка ушла!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте это

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domain.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://your-ip:dgango-gunicorn-bind-port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
     root /path/to/project;
    }

    location /media/ {
     root /path/to/project;
    }

}
```

[Вот отличный гайд](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru)

Comment: Спасибо большое!